# Classification problem with 2 level features

Tags: machine-learning, classification, binary-classification

Consider an automated house, where we can collect router data every minute. The objective is to predict router fail/no fail (1/0) in a future time window.

The router sends data at two different levels every minute:

1. Router properties of the device: Memory, Temperature, Usage (router level)
2. Data collected from N different IoT devices, received rates, signals (IoT device level)

Since the target is defined at the router level, how could the IoT individual data be incorporated into the classifier?

Comment: as the question is put, IoT data are irrelevant

Comment: What if, only IoT data is available to predict router failure?

Comment: The question is: are the IoT data predictors for router failure or not? If, for example, certain IoT measurements come before router failures, then IoT data are predictors, else they are irrelevant

Comment: Indeed, let´s put it this way: the data coming from the router & IoT devices in the last 15 min is used to predict failure in the next hour.

Comment: In any case you can use both as they are (for example in a multidimensional input)